# File size on disk is ~46x what windows says the actual size to be

Tags: filesystems, file-management

Now, I can get when it takes a few extra Kb to stow  away a few files, but when it takes more space than the file itself, and 46x more at that, I start to think something's up.
[image]

I'm installing a TeX distribution, fresh.

So far, the file size is over 46 times the actual file size. This seems ridiculous.

Why do these files take so much more space than they should? why is it so wasteful? I've considered the stripe size on FAT32 as a limitation, but looking at the number of files, each stripe would need to be about 1.5MB minimum.

Compare this to the rest of the files on my disk. The size is 2.90 GB, and the size on disk is 9.24GB, giving a ratio of about 1:3.17 size:storage

Comment: have you tried to confirm this information using a command? To me it seems the UI is not being updated properly. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813826/get-folder-size-from-windows-command-line

Comment: @arielnmz the installation is still in progress. The space will be much bigger when finished. As we speak, it's grown to over 60 GB. Also I have tried running the command. I get a "UNC paths are not supported" error.

Comment: @DanielB consider for a moment the difference between 50% and 4500%, and that the user got that error with 500GB worth of files, while I got it with 245MB, and diverging. and that I explained the fault of the answers there, and why it couldn't apply in this situation.

Comment: No. It most definitely does apply. A LaTeX distribution consists of thousands of very small files. Indeed, you have 12,147 files, each of which will count as multiples of 1 MiB, Which is, coincidentally, *super* close to the 11.9 GiB Windows shows.

Comment: @DanielB but windows says the average size of the files is 20k. Who even has a stripe size of >1Mb?

Comment: Please read my answer to the other question. It fully explains this behavior, which is specific to shared folders.

Comment: The percentage difference is meaningless.  If you have 1,000 files each containing 2 bytes, and a block size of 4K, the files will consume 200,000% of their actual size.

Comment: Is the file system NTFS or something else?

Comment: @fixer1234 you can calculate the stripe Size  needed in the sc above. It's above 1mb

Comment: Why would it need to be above 1 MiB? It’s just that some files are larger than 1 MiB, so they count as 2 MiB or maybe even more. Also, it’s block size (or, in Windows terms, cluster size). Striping is something else entirely.